# Rendering Issue in Low-Poly 3D Model

Tags: modeling, rendering, topology

I am currently working on a low-poly 3D model, and I'm encountering an issue with the rendering of a particular polygon. The problem is that it renders as if there is an edge cutting through the middle, although there is no such edge in the model.

I have checked the geometry, made sure there are no duplicate vertices, and verified the normals, but the problem persists. I'm reaching out to seek your expertise in troubleshooting and resolving this rendering anomaly.

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has insights into potential solutions, your assistance would be greatly appreciated. Additionally, if you require specific details, code snippets, or screenshots to better understand the problem, please let me know, and I'll provide them promptly.

3d Object for better inspect:
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/low-poly-boot-52a88056866646b19dbe4bd000ae0407

[image]

Comment: Hello, L. Text.. welcome! It certainly looks to me as if Leander's link should answer your question. If it does, we should close out this question as a duplicate, just to keep the archive tidy. (Nothing personal, you understand.) If not, please edit your question to explain why not. This almost certainly looks to be due to the way non-planar quads are triangulated internally, for rendering.